# How to access Windows 7 command prompt from a Linux machine?

Tags: linux, windows-7, windows-7-x64

I need to access Windows 7 command prompt from a linux machine through "telnet or ssh".

I tried openssh but I am unable to connect.

Please give your ideas to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have to login via remote desktop. http://www.7tutorials.com/connecting-windows-remote-desktop-ubuntu